# Missing classpath variable in eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I defined a classpath variable called `shared_src` in Eclipse under:

`Window->Preferences->Java->Build Path->Classpath Variables`

The variable points to a folder (`C:\some_source`).Now, I try to link that source folder using this variable.

In project properties, I go to:

`Java Build Path -> Source -> Link Source` and click on the `Variables` button.

The list of variables that shows up in the "Select Path Variable" pop-up does not include the `shared_src` variable that I defined initially.

My question is, is the `shared_src` variable supposed to be available for linking source folders, and if so, how can I change my Eclipse setup to be able to use the variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Window > Preferences
then to
General > Workspace > Linked Resources
and define your folder here. Then you can use defined variable in project.